# Is Magento 2's ScopeConfig lazyloaded?

Tags: magento2, configuration

When i need to retrieve config values, i usually inject `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` to use.

But i have a concern about the `core_config_data` table getting too big and at one point, loading the whole table will decrease performance?

I believe the config object will construct from the whole table when it is loaded, is this correct? If it is so, has there been any concerns about performance when the table gets too big or if a few of the records have huge values?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: @danronmoon not many for now

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry about this particular table.

There will be other hurdles elsewhere that you need to overcome if you are dealing with large stores with lot of extensions.

At the moment for me if you have a multisite with a large catalogue crons are running for long time and using a lot of resource.

Also before 2.3.3 sorted out bulk product updates as a separate queued process this was a sticking point.

2.3.3 includes updates to MSI which has increased performance. 2.3 versions prior to this suffer.

Also if writing your own stuff for example look at view models instead of blocks. So in summary try to use latest techniques where possible. The platform is continually evolving.

Comment: Thanks for future warnings, i'm aware of other performance issues, but just in case some modules may utilize the core_config_data table too much and storing a huge JSON for example, was just wondering if that could be another performance issue even though not much compared to other concerns, but they build up over time you know.